# Predictive Monitoring (Nagios?)

Tags: monitoring, nagios

i am searching for a predictive monitoring solution which is actually free and able to discover trends. I've been reading about a lot of monitoring software like Zabbix, Zenoss, OpenNMS etc. but it doesnt seem that any of these are able to discover trends (e.g. the used memory of a webapplication increases from day to day)...

We are currently monitoring our systems with Nagios, but as everyone knows, Nagios is perfect to monitor stuff but not pretty good at analyzing/reporting...

Is there a way to implement predictive monitoring at the moment? Like the monitoring software is able to discover trends and throws an alert *before* something gets to a critical point?

Thanks in advance and sry for my poor english!

Greets, 
Marley

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for Serverfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i have been waiting quiet a while now and it seems not even Stackoverflow is able to help.

I decided to gave up on this and hope for Zabbix to implement the feature within 2012.. They said it might be released with version 2.2

:(!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you were able to solve this issue, but i have this small project that may help you out https://github.com/ricardomaraschini/nada

Answer (score -1):

Take look at  www.opservices.com.br. It's nagios based and have predictive baseline monitoring and alarming.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just checked the website but it doesnt seem to have a non commercial version...